# Task execution is not working after lunching the task in spring cloud data flow

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I have created one Spring boot application with `@EnablesTask` annotation and try to print the arguments in log.

```
package com.custom.samplejob;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.cloud.task.configuration.EnableTask;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableTask
public class TaskConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner() {
        return args -> {
            System.out.println(args);
        };
    }
}
```

After I have run that `mvn clean install` to have the jar in local maven repo.

```
com.custom:samplejob:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Using custom docker-compose to run spring cloud data flow locally on windows using the below parameters

```
set HOST_MOUNT_PATH=C:\Users\user\.m2 (Local maven repository mounting)

set DOCKER_MOUNT_PATH=/root/.m2/

set DATAFLOW_VERSION=2.7.1

set SKIPPER_VERSION=2.6.1

docker-compose up
```

Using the below commend to register the app

```
app register --type task --name custom-task-trail-1 --uri maven://com.custom:samplejob:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Created task using UI(below URL) and lunch the task. Task was successfully launched.

```
http://localhost:9393/dashboard/#/tasks-jobs/tasks
```

These are the logs I can see in the docker-compose up terminal,

```
dataflow-server    | 2021-02-15 13:20:41.673  INFO 1 --- [nio-9393-exec-9] o.s.c.d.spi.local.LocalTaskLauncher      : Preparing to run an application from com.custom:samplejob:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT. This may take some time if the artifact must be downloaded from a remote host.
dataflow-server    | 2021-02-15 13:20:41.693  INFO 1 --- [nio-9393-exec-9] o.s.c.d.spi.local.LocalTaskLauncher      : Command to be executed: /usr/lib/jvm/jre-11.0.8/bin/java -jar /root/.m2/repository/com/custom/samplejob/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/samplejob-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --name=dsdsds --spring.cloud.task.executionid=38
dataflow-server    | 2021-02-15 13:20:41.702  INFO 1 --- [nio-9393-exec-9] o.s.c.d.spi.local.LocalTaskLauncher      : launching task custom-task-trail-1-48794885-9a0a-4c46-a2a1-299bf91763ad
dataflow-server    |    Logs will be in /tmp/4921907601400/custom-task-trail-1-48794885-9a0a-4c46-a2a1-299bf91763ad
```

But in task execution list, it's doesn't show the status and start date and end date of that task executions,

[image]

can some one help me to resolve this or am I missing anything here in local installation or task spring boot implementation wise?

Comment: Can you share the logs in `/tmp/4921907601400/custom-task-trail-1-48794885-9a0a-4c46-a2a1-299bf91763ad`? If not, do you see any errors?

Comment: Hi @MahmoudBenHassine - I try to get the logs from the below commend, but its saying that no such file or directory. 
`docker exec -it skipper more /tmp/4921907601400/custom-task-trail-1-48794885-9a0a-4c46-a2a1-299bf91763ad `
Output `more: stat of /tmp/4921907601400/custom-task-trail-1-48794885-9a0a-4c46-a2a1-299bf91763ad failed: No such file or directory`
Can you guide me where to check this logs ?

Comment: You should look for the logs in the same host where the dataflow server is running.

Comment: currently dataflow server was running on my windows using docker-compose. I dont see any errors on dataflow-server container logs

Comment: these are the logs for the above problem,
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'taskLifecycleListener'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid TaskExecution, ID 2 not found @MahmoudBenHassine

Comment: Please edit the question and post the full stacktrace of the error to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have enabled kubernetes on docker desktop and installed spring data flow server top of that.
And I tried with docker uri to register app and generate docker image using the jib-maven-plugin.

Now its works the sample task application in my case.